# What signature should be used for binding to objective-c parameter of type "Class<...>"?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

Objctive-C declaration:

```
+ (instancetype)queryWithClass:(Class<LYRQueryable>)queryableClass;
```

How to bind in c# the parameter of type `Class<LYRQueryable>`?
I have binding for `LYRQueryable`, but how to declare/pass the backended objective-c class for it?

Answer (score 1):

```
objCClass = new ObjCRuntime.Class(typeof(LYRQueryable));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ObjCRuntime.Class` type:

```
NSObject Query (Class queryableClass);
```